# Game Center to Bluestacks

Tags: clash-of-clans

I linked my Clash of Clans account from my iPhone to Bluestacks on my laptop. I then removed it in my BlueStacks, and now I want to link my iPhone Clash of Clans back to my Bluestacks again. Could someone please tell me how?

Comment: If you had linked your BlueStacks' village to your GooglePlay account, you can log into any device. As for using the link feature again (for the second time), [you'll need to contact Supercell](mailto:clashofclans.feedback@supercell.com). | Bah. Email links doesn't work. I'll just presume you know how to copy-paste.

Answer (score 2):

If your account is now connected to your Google+ you can now Log-in your Clash Of Clans account to your [Bluestack](http://bluestack.com) application.

GO to: Bluestacks Settings

then Advance Settings
add account (your Google account that you use in COC)
Then open Clash Of Clan game.

go to Setting.

Click Disconnect/connect. 
pick your email..

(game will refresh)

pop up will appear

Type in All caps CONFIRM.. 
viola

having trouble, you can Follow this steps from this site, [Clash of clans Transfer village account](http://www.mycoclab.com/2015/06/how-transfer-coc-account.html)

Comment: It would be helpful if you added a summery of the steps from the site you just posted. Then, if the site ever goes down, other people can still see how to fix the issue.