# How to change iPhone Clash of Clans account to Android

Tags: clash-of-clans

I lost my iPhone about a year ago and my mom just now trusted me enough to get me a new phone but the problem is it's not an iPhone. Is there a way I can change my Clash of Clans iPhone accont to Android?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Game Center to Bluestacks](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/214180/game-center-to-bluestacks)

Answer (score 1):

For this to work, you need access to your old credentials (village).

- Another iOS device (ie. an iPad or iPhone)
- Your village binded to a GameCenter account.

If you have previously transferred your village or not have both of these, you cannot transfer or retrieve your village.

---

Transferring from iOS to Android has a different procedure because you can't log into GameCenter on an Android device. Due to this, you'll have to do manual transfer.

1. Open Clash of Clans on your iOS device. Ensure you're logged in to the GameCenter account which you have bounded your village to.
2. Select the cogwheel, above the shop button.
3. Select "Link a Device"
4. Select "This is the old device"
5. Select "Transfer to Other"
6. On your Android device, repeat Steps 1 to 3. **Do not close Clash of Clans on either devices until you've linked your villages!**
7. Select "This is the new device"
8. Enter the code displayed on the iOS device.
9. Follow the on-screen prompts.